# Pass array in WhereIn and Order results by same array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass an array of lists of post_id from post_views table to posts table. 
What I got so far is, when I pass the $newsTagRetreived array to $posts, it only gives me first posts. 
Current code looks like this:

```
$newsTagRetreived = NewsTag::where('created_at', '>', 
                            \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateTimeString())
                            ->orderBy('views','desc')
                            ->pluck('post_id')
                            ->implode(', ');
// dd($newsTagRetreived);
```

this returns me exactly all lists of posts_id I need in exact order I need but only 1 post.

In the post,

```
$posts = Post::where('post_status', 'publish')
->where('post_type', 'post')->whereIn('ID',[$newsTagRetreived])->paginate('12');
```

How do I get all posts in the same order as passed by $newsTagRetreived in $posts? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//...
->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(ID, ". implode(",",$newsTagRetreived) ." )"))->paginate('12');
//...
```

See http://oldblog.codebyjeff.com/blog/2015/02/laravel-quick-tip-order-by-raw